# Can I upload image or a file to WKWebView input field programmatically?

Tags: swift, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have a web app where users can pick an image, upload it and do stuff with it. I am building an iOS app that opens my web app inside `WKWebView`. Currently, users can pick an image and upload it on the iOS app. But I want to implement feature that would allow users to edit the picture. I know how to implement editing picture, but I am not sure if I can upload file to `<input/>` field on `WKWebView` programmatically.

Comment: Hi , it's sure . You can do that , if problems can share code here .

Comment: I do not have a problem in code, I am wondering if WKWebview has such support. If you have a link or general idea of how can I do that, it would be very helpful. I could not find a solution on WKWbeview docs or on other communities

Comment: OK, now not having sample code , later if will update here .

Answer (score 1):

I have a Html code used in browser of Windows before . After trying in iOS ,it also can select image from iOS . What you need to modify is upload data to server .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Upload Image</title>

    <style type="text/css">
            /*
        css
         */
            #fileimg {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid #eee;
            }

            .Btn {
                width: 100px;
                background: #4BCD61;
                border: 0px;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //JS
        function fileClick() {
            document.getElementById('file').click()
        }//

        function upCh(file) {
            let img = document.getElementById('fileimg')
            let formData = new FormData()
            let imgUrl = file.files[0];
            if (imgUrl) {
                formData.append('file', imgUrl);
                /*
                 up load to server .
                */
            }
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="" onchange="upCh(this)" />
    <br />
    <img id="fileimg" src="" />
    <br />
    <button class="Btn" onclick="fileClick()">Upload Image</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

If want to interface with Html , you can use [invoke javascript method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wkwebview.evaluatejavascript?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to Native .

```
var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
var wk = new WKWebView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds, config);
var js = (NSString) "document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 'bar'";
WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) => { 
  if(err != null)
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine(err);
  }
  if(result != null)
  {
     System.Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
};
wk.EvaluateJavaScript(js, handler);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time and providing this solution. I guess this will work. Just to make sure, I can't actually set file to an input field like normal input field behaviour, but what can I do, is to upload to a server. Is that right?

Comment: @Abdurakhmon Hi , what's the meaning of *set file to an input field like normal input field behaviour* , you can explain more about *normal input* .

Comment: I mean setting file programmatically to <input> field. By normal behavior I meant user selecting a file and the file gets set to <input> field.

Comment: @Abdurakhmon If you mean using C# code to transfer image data to wkwebview , it's possible . You can use Native code to invoke JavaScript .